# While learning older material for objective-C for iOS, when coming across retain/release statements, do I ignore?

Tags: ios, objective-c

While trying to work older tutorials and material for learning iOS development, when I come across retain/release in a code, is it okay to just ignore it (and act is if ARC takes care of it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore it, however it is a good idea to understand what's going on. There's still a lot of older code out there you may need to read/use/modify. Also, a working knowledge of memory management is useful when debugging memory issues.

Comment: Are there any specific circumstances where memory management will have to be handled manually? Or will I be using ARC for 99% of my iOS development purposes?

Comment: If you're writing all new code all the time, then yes, ARC will take care of the details 99% of the time. If you find yourself using an open source framework or working with legacy code that does not use ARC, then you will run into it far more often.

Comment: Since the compiler will return an error when working with ARC and using retain/release, does this mean that if you work with legacy code without the use of ARC, you will have to code 100% without ARC as well?

Comment: @stevendao no, you can enable / disable ARC on a per-file basis, which is probably explained in the links in the other answer

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine but I would recommend reading up on converting from non ARC to ARC

[Migrating to ARC](http://www.daveoncode.com/2011/10/24/migration-to-arc-automatic-reference-counting-using-xcode-4-2-refactor/)

or

[Migrating code to ARC](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/articles/migrating-your-code-to-objective-c-arc/)

Comment: Yep I'm currently reading through it, just wanted a quick and clear answer to that question. Thanks!